# Unable to add multiple AsyncTypeahead in single page

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am currently encountering an issue where I am unable to assign dynamic options for the dynamic AsyncTypeahead created.

How do I add options as dynamic to individual typeahead list ?

Has anyone encountered similiar issue ?
I have highlighted the place where we pass options.

```
    Sample code:


    <AsyncTypeahead
                            labelKey="id"
                            **options={options}**
                            inputProps={{id:`${key}`}}
                            clearButton={true}
                            minLength={5}
                            isLoading={isLoading}
                            filterBy={filterByCallback}
                            onSearch={this.handleSearch}
                            placeholder="Search "
                            onChange={this.handleTypeAheadChange(key)}
                            renderMenuItemChildren={(option) => (
                                <div>
                                    {option.id} {option.name}
                                </div>
                            )}

                        />

     <AsyncTypeahead
                             labelKey="id"
                             **options={options1}**
                             inputProps={{id:`${key}`}}
                             clearButton={true}
                             minLength={5}
                             isLoading={isLoading}
                             filterBy={filterByCallback}
                             onSearch={this.handleSearch}
                             placeholder="Search "
                             onChange={this.handleTypeAheadChange(key)}
                             renderMenuItemChildren={(option) => (
                                 <div>
                                     {option.id} {option.name}
                                 </div>
                             )}

                        />


       <AsyncTypeahead
                               labelKey="id"
                               **options={options2}**
                               inputProps={{id:`${key}`}}
                               clearButton={true}
                               minLength={5}
                               isLoading={isLoading}
                               filterBy={filterByCallback}
                               onSearch={this.handleSearch}
                               placeholder="Search "
                               onChange={this.handleTypeAheadChange(key)}
                               renderMenuItemChildren={(option) => (
                                   <div>
                                       {option.id} {option.name}
                                   </div>
                               )}

                        />

/**/
 handleTypeAheadChange = name => values => {
    this.setState({
        [name]: values[0]
    });

}
```

Comment: It seems like you generally have the right idea. What does your `handleTypeAheadChange` method look like?

Comment: @ericgio: Thank you for your reply. I have edit my post and added the handleTypeAheadChange as requested.  If onSearch allows event to be passed then issue can be solved but the problem is that, onSearch allows only value :(

Comment: Is the `key` value dynamic or are you setting that manually on each typeahead?

Comment: That’s dynamic ..

Comment: Does the `key` value serve any purpose beyond the code in your example? Why can't you just pass a unique `name` value to `handleTypeAheadChange` and use that? Also, it seems wrong to set the same `id` on all three typeaheads.

Comment: Actually the key, here is the index value through array map for rendering the asynctypeahead. I have an option to allow user to click on add button. Clicking on the button, adds new asynctypeahead component. The problem here is assigning options to each asynctypeahead component..  hope I dint confuse you :D

Comment: Since we assign options to each asynctypeahead onSearch, I am having difficulty in that..  if it was static then it’s straight forward ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to take a similar approach with `handleSearch` as you do with `handleTypeAheadChange`:

```
<AsyncTypeahead
  onSearch={this.handleSearch(key)}
  options={this.state[`options${key}`] || []}
  ...
/>

handleSearch = (key) => (query) => {
  /* Do async fetch... */

  this.setState({
    [`options${key}`]: results,
  });
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :D... I was missing the piece, handleSearch = (key) => (query).... thank you again.. Hope my question was not bad :D